# reactjs setState performance

Tags: reactjs

Assume dropdownState, selectAll have a default value of **false**, and now we try to set dropdownState to **true**, The first one is doing a better job to not mutate the state.
however I want to compare between bottom two case, which one is running faster?

CASE 1:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
            dropdownState: true,
            selectAll: prevState.selectAll
        }
    });
```

CASE 2:

```
 this.setState({
        dropdownState: true
    });
```

Render function is like

```
{dropdownState}
{selectAll}
```

Comment: Setup a perf environment using `react-addons-perf` and run these two atleast 10 times, you will know it. I'm guessing the case 2 will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second one will be a little faster (maybe not noticeable) because if you are not changing or mutating the object React will avoid rendering `selectAll`. You can also use the `shouldComponentUpdate` life cycle hook inheriting from `React.PureComponent` instead of `React.Component` for a fine tuning on your render.

You can find more info on optimization and testing at this link [Optimizing performance](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html). Hope that helps you!